# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, android-espresso

I have been trying to perform a simple UI test using Espresso and all my tests fail with the same exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation

It's a beginners guide in the use of esspresso [here](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/introduction-to-android/ui-testing-basics-with-espresso-f7ec4669-cd03-4dc4-b8f0-88b3803dbca3). I have already found similar questions but the most relevant ones to me are unanswered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52888861/android-testing-give-a-illegalstateexception-no-instrumentation-registered) - I presume it is because they didn't paint the whole picture so here is my code. I will only show one test because they all fail with the exact same error:

**build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.github.vinge1718.myrestaurants"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        //testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
}
```

**build.gradle (Project: MyRestaurant)**

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

correction here are the **two** tests. I don't think the error is in any way related to the tests themselves but the configurations - I stand corrected though

**(MainActivityInstrumentationTest.java)**

```
package io.github.vinge1718.myrestaurants;

import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityInstrumentationTest {
    private String mStringToBetyped;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void initValidString() {
        // Specify a valid string.
        mStringToBetyped = "Portland";
    }

    @Test
    public void validateEditText(){
        onView(withId(R.id.locationEditText))
                .perform(typeText(mStringToBetyped), closeSoftKeyboard())
                .check(matches(withText(mStringToBetyped)));
    }

    @Test
    public void locationIsSentToRestaurantActivity(){
        String location = "Portland";
        onView(withId(R.id.locationEditText)).perform(typeText(location));
        onView(withId(R.id.findRestaurantsButton)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.locationTextView)).check(matches(withText("Here are all the Restaurants near " + location)));
    }
}
```

I have tried following this espresso set up documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup) but I keep getting the same error:

> Started running tests
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must
> run under a registering instrumentation. at
> androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.java:50)
> at
> androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(InstrumentationRegistry.java:101)
> at
> androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.(ActivityTestRule.java:144)
> at
> androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.(ActivityTestRule.java:120)
> at
> androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.(ActivityTestRule.java:103)
> at
> io.github.vinge1718.myrestaurants.MainActivityInstrumentationTest.(MainActivityInstrumentationTest.java:25)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at
> android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
> at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at
> org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) at
> android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
> at
> android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2075)
>
> Tests ran to completion.

Here is my test configurations as decribed in the espresso set up [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup):

[image]

Comment: someone answered and resolved mine issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53341010/10096288

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because of libraries `androidx` is conflicting with `com.android.support.test`. If you want to use jetpack, you must convert all of test library to androidx, if you don't want that way, just delete your `androidx` libraries and use all `com.android.support.test`. Check my latest answer in [Android Instrumentation Testing: No instrumentation registered Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53193247/android-instrumentation-testing-no-instrumentation-registered-error/53341010#53341010). Hope this help you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and there difference between a test which exercise methods in classes, those standard unit [tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests#setup) go in `app/src/test/java/<package>`.  UI [tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/) that interact with buttons, edit texts, etc require expresso and go in `app/src/androidTest/java/<package>`.  It took me several reads of the documentation and I wasted a day before I figured out the distinction.

```
|____app
  |
  | ____src 
  |   |____androidTest
  |   |  |____java
  |   |     |____<package>
  |   |        |____ MainActivityInstrumentationTest.java  # expresso here 
  |   |____test
  |      |____java
  |         |____<package>
  |            |____ MainActivityInstrumentationTest.java  # not here
```

Comment: My project is set up exactly like you have described. I think android studio 3.2.1 does that automatically. My UI tests path looks like: [app - src - androidTest - java - package.name - tests.java]

Answer (score -3):

What worked for me is to completely change back from

> androidX

to

> com.android.support

libraries in the build.gradle

Please note: You might have to re import the libraries in your class e.g.

```
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner;
```

to

```
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner;
```

Also make sure you always clean and rebuilt the project after each addition or removal library from build.gradle.