# Android Instrumentation Testing: No instrumentation registered Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-espresso

I am trying to write Android Instrumented test using Espresso. When I run the test I get this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.

I can't understand what this error means.

I will briefly explain what I am doing in my test. I followed the [samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing) given by google and [EspressoTesting Tutorial](https://github.com/LearnShareKnowledge/EspressoTestingUi)

```
@SmallTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ActivityInputTest {

   @Rule
   public ActivityTestRule<ActivityInput> aiRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(ActivityInput.class);


   @Before
   public void setUp(){}
}
```

When I run the test the error occurs at annotation `@Rule`. Can I get some explanation why this happens or what is the issue behind this? I am not interested in working code but more on the actual problem behind the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also experienced error exactly same with you, because I used `androidx` library. I suggest you to check your libraries in build.gradle and change your dependencies for UI test like these block codes:

```
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2"
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Choose one of them, using `com.android.support.test`, or `androidx` library, because if we use them together, they will conflict each other. Hope this can help you to resolve error `No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.`

Comment: This is not a solution. It just gets rid of the Exception by removing the actual generator of this exception `Androidx` test orchestration. I need to use Test orchestrator for my espresso tests, cannot use the regular  `com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2`

Comment: You have to move all libraries to `androidx`, because both libraries conflicting each other. Just choose one of them, if you want to use libraries in Androidx, covert the `com.android.support.test:runner` to `androidx.test:runner:1.1.0` 
 check the complete documentation in https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project

Answer (score 0):

Changing how I retrieved the context from:

```
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
}
```

to the deprecated way :

```
import org.robolectric.RuntimeEnvironment;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    context = RuntimeEnvironment.application;
}
```

solved the issue for me.

Comment: Where is `RuntimeEnvironment`? What gradle dependency do I need to add? And what package do I need to import it from?

Comment: `org.robolectric.RuntimeEnvironment` from `implementation group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'robolectric', version: robolectric_version`

Comment: Please [edit] your quesiton to include these details for future visitors.